# vbsでphp置換がhtml対象でしか動作しない

Tags: vbs

vbsで複数のphpファイルの内容を一括で、そのファイル自身の名前に変更するプログラムを作りたいです。

以下のようなコードを作成しましたが、html以外では動作してくれません。
どうしたら良いですか？

```
Option Explicit '変数の宣言を省略させないためのものです。

Const TARGET_FOLDER = "C:\Users\drive\aaa"     '※フォルダを指定
Const REPLACE_FROM = "so" '※置換前文字列
Dim   REPLACE_TO                    '  置換後文字列

Const ForReading = 1 '読み込み
Const ForWriting = 2 '書きこみ（上書きモード）
Const ForAppending = 8 '書きこみ（追記モード）

Dim strFilePath, infile, outfile, strData, strExt '変数を宣言
Dim objFSO, objFolder, objFile, objSubFolder, objTXT '変数を宣言
Set objFSO = WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 'ドライブ・フォルダ・ファイルなどを操作できるオブジェクトです。
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(TARGET_FOLDER)

For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
    strFilePath = objFSO.BuildPath(TARGET_FOLDER, objFile.Name)
    strExt = objFSO.GetExtensionName(objFile.Name)
    If LCase(strExt) = "html" Then
        Set infile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strFilePath,ForReading)
        strData = infile.ReadAll
        infile.Close
        Set infile = Nothing
        Set outfile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strFilePath,ForWriting)   '(上書き)
        REPLACE_TO = objFile.Name '※自身のファイル名
        outfile.Write Replace(strData,REPLACE_FROM,REPLACE_TO)
        outfile.Close
        Set outfile = Nothing
    End If
Next

Set objFolder = Nothing
Set objFSO = Nothing

MsgBox "終了", vbInformation
```

Answer (score 0):

`For` 文の中の `If` 文で拡張子をチェックしており、現状だとここで「html の場合のみ」処理をしているようなので、PHP を対象にしたい場合は以下のように書き換えてみてください。

**変更前:**

```
    strExt = objFSO.GetExtensionName(objFile.Name)
    If LCase(strExt) = "html" Then
```

**変更後:**

```
    strExt = objFSO.GetExtensionName(objFile.Name)
    If LCase(strExt) = "php" Then
```

Comment: まず「php」に変えたら「ファイルの最後を超えた入力を行おうとしました。」って出たから0バイトのファイルを消し、そしたら「プロシージャの呼び出し、または因数が不正です。」って出て、それでも実行すると0バイトのファイルが増える(ファイルの中身が消えていく)謎が発生中です・・・・